# Laravel 5.3 route auth not working on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Auth not working on hostgetor shared hosting but it's working well on local. please help..

```
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('admin_template'); 
}); 
Route::auth();

Route::get('/admins', 'HomeController@index');

//Categories 
Route::get('/categories', 'CategoriesController@index');
Route::post('/addCategory', 'CategoriesController@store');
```

Comment: Provide read/write permission to your project folder, If you have write permissions on your Live server for the folder app/storage it will start work for you

Answer (score 1):

The built in builder for all authentication routes is actually `Auth::routes()`.